# Reverse key and value in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'd like to reverse keys and values of the dictionary. I.e from source dictionary `Dictionary<int, string>`, I would like to get `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`. There is `List<int>` because the value can be in source dictionary multiple times under different keys.

Example:

```
{
  1: "A"
  2: "A"
  3: "A"
  4: "B"
  5: "B"
  6: "C"
  7: "D"
}
```

would transform to:

```
{
  "A": [1,2,3]
  "B": [4,5]
  "C": [6]
  "D": [7]
}
```

Thanks for help.

**EDIT:**

OK, with help from you guys I was able to understand a bit about this algorithm.
Now I see two possible solutions (among others) and don't know what is the real difference between them as the result seems to be the same.

Are there any performance issues?

```
var byLookup = actions.ToLookup(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.AsEnumerable());
var byGroupBy = actions.GroupBy(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.AsEnumerable());
```

**EDIT 2:**

I ended up using just

```
var byLookup = actions.ToLookup(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key)
```

I didn't expected it would be this simple.
Thanks all.

Comment: Are you trying to create a lookup from a Dictionary? If this is the case, the ToLookup() extension method is your friend.

Comment: @B... I tried to figure it out, but couldn't get my head over the GroupBy method with all the parameters and overloads.

Comment: Just `var byLookup = actions.ToLookup(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key)` is enough, you don't really need the call to ToDictionary on that one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a fairly simple LINQ expression:

```
var res = dict
    .GroupBy(p => p.Value)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(pp => pp.Key).ToList());
```

First, you group by the value. This creates groups with strings as keys, and `KeyValuePair<int,string>` as its items.

Then you convert the groups to a dictionary by using groups's key for the dictionary key, and "flattening" the keys of the original dictionary into a list with `ToList()`.

Comment: Thank's for your help. I updated my question, can you have a look at it please?

Comment: @sidon The two approaches that you show are pretty much the same, because in the end you get a dictionary anyway. You shouldn't leave `AsEnumerable()` there, though, unless you know for sure that you are not going to enumerate the lists in the dictionary more than once.

Comment: @sidon If having a lookup object instead of a dictionary object is acceptable, you could skip `ToDictionary` altogether.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get your required result as follows:

```
var result = source
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value, x => x.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

This gives the same result as [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19518585/61989), but moves the mapping of the KeyValuePair into the group by clause

Answer (score -3):

```
dic = {1: "A",  2: "A",  3: "A",  4: "B",  5: "B",  6: "C",  7: "D"}

rev_dic = {}
for key in dic:
    new_value = dic[key]
    if not new_value in rev_dic:
        rev_dic[new_value] = []
    rev_dic[new_value].append(key)

for new_value in rev_dic:
    rev_dic[new_value].sort()

print(rev_dic)
```

Will print:

```
{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5], 'C': [6], 'D': [7]}
```

Comment: Question is about C#